# "Why we are here ?" vs "Why are we here ?"

Tags: questions

I would like to ask this question to an audience during a presentation and follow with an explanation. I wonder which form is correct—*Why we are here?* or *Why are we here?*

I understand that the correct form should be *Why are we here?*, but the form *Why we are here* in the context of religion, for example, is quite popular.

Is *Why we are here?* a grammatical mistake? If so, then what is the correct context in which to use *Why we are here*?

I tried to search Google, but the sentence is too general and it is hard to find anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["I'm not sure what the right way is"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51123/im-not-sure-what-the-right-way-is)

Answer (score 1):

A rhetorical question is not meant to be answered and thus becomes a leading question, and therefore the declarative *why we are here* is rather suitable than the imperative *why are we here* having people construe to immediately vacate the premises not to mention during your presentation for the more significant things to do.

Answer (score 0):

*Why we are here?* in common American English, would be a preface to an answer to a question regarding a specific situation, quandary, or problem.

Example:

> Why we are here is easy to explain. We offered an inferior product at too high a price. And so, accordingly, we went out of business because the darned thing wouldn't sell.

*Why are we here?* is generally a philosophical question, followed by more specific queries.

Example:

> Why are we here? I mean, what is our purpose on this planet, and in this existence? Is there a grand design, or is it all random happenstance?

Comment: If you could include some sources to support your answer that would increase the credibility and validity of the answer